# Escape My HTML Character

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement where if user enters anything in the free text field, it should be written on Page, problem i am facing when user enters any html character, it doesnt write anything, as it takes it as html character instead of normal text.

> http://jsfiddle.net/mJwwS/

```
$('#add').on('click',function(){
  $('#hey').html($('#oye').val());   
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method instead:

```
$('#hey').text($('#oye').val());
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mJwwS/1/